# Java Class Clarification

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I am not looking for code or anything, just some explanations on how all of this works.

Its a homework assignemnt.

I am supposed to create a housing complex (like a home neighborhood).
each house is like a townhome.

the neighborhood has a name, a number of houses, a number of garages, has security staff.

each house has its own individual features like number of rooms, rent etc.
each staff has its own individual features like staff type, name etc.

I need to be able to create multiple complexes and the houses/staff must be dynamic like an array list so i can add or remove.

what can i look up to help me get started?

Comment: Do you have any class notes? Reference Text Books? I was usually able to get started based on those.

Comment: A somewhat natural analogy when thinking about classes is to compare the attributes of a class with the properties of an instance (for example, the class "bear" may have an attribute called "size" that defines how large the represented object is), and its methods with the behavior of the instances (for example, a bear can "eat()", "sleep()", "grow()", etc.)

Comment: I understand a concept like this, but using the bear as an example:
the BEAR has 2 arms.
each arm has its own properties. and if i want to make the bear have 3 arms I could do that too.. how do i do something like this? @G.Bach

Comment: If there's a static number of attributes, you can put them in an array or make one field for each of them; if there's a dynamic number of them, use some dynamic sort of data structure, like a set or a list.

Answer (score 2):

Look into how java implements Object Oriented programming concepts:

[Oracle's Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html)

Just like a class can have a field `int` as in

```
public class Person {
    public int age;
}
```

it can also have a field of a class type like `Person`

```
public class Person {
    public int age;
    public Person bestFriend;
    // or
    public List<Person> otherFriends;
}
```

Keep reading up on the subject [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html).

Comment: I understand how to do this, but my problem is using multiple classes.

Comment: See above, classes can have references to other class objects.

Comment: Please read the links I've added, they will give you all the information you need. Skip the parts you understand and go to more complex sections.